# Add List to Picker.Item component from JSON data react native expo

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, expo, asyncstorage

I want to add data to the <Picker.Item> component of the JSON that I pulled from AsyncStorage.
but the result is an error
the following code that I made:

```
constructor(props) {
      super(props);    
      this.state = {
         url: '',
         
      }
      this.checkurl();      
    }



checkurl = async () => {    
    
    const urlget = await AsyncStorage.getItem('url');        
    if(urlget) {        
      this.setState({ url: urlget });
    } else {
      console.log('data url empty');
    }
  }


render () {
    const urlListrender = this.state.url.map((item) =>
    <Picker.Item label={item.alias} value={item.url} key={item.id}/>
    );

    return(

        <View>
          <Picker 
              style={styles.pickerText}
              selectedValue={this.state.url}
              onValueChange={(itemValue,itemIndex) => this.setState({url: itemValue})}>              
              {urlListrender}
          </Picker>
       </View>

        )   
}
```

what mistake have I made?
how do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

try the following. I made changes to a few things.

```
constructor(props) {
      super(props);    
      this.state = {
         url: [],
         
      }
    }

componentDidMount(){
  this.checkurl();      
}

checkurl = async () => {    
    
    const urlget = await AsyncStorage.getItem('url');        
    if(urlget) {        
      this.setState({ url: urlget });
    } else {
      console.log('data url empty');
    }
  }


render () {
   if (this.state.url === undefined || this.state.url === null) return null;

   const urlListrender = this.state.url.map((item) =>
    <Picker.Item label={item.alias} value={item.url} key={item.id}/>
    );

    return(

        <View>
          <Picker 
              style={styles.pickerText}
              selectedValue={this.state.url}
              onValueChange={(itemValue,itemIndex) => this.setState({url: itemValue})}>              
              {urlListrender}
          </Picker>
       </View>

        )   
}
```

Comment: an error message appears like this: TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...this.state.url.map...')

Comment: check for if (this.state.url !== undefined) instead of this.state.url.length === 0, but i think the problem is that there's nothing in the asynstorage. Try console logging after getting the data to see if there's really data there.

Comment: this is the result when I add console.log('url login :', urlget); after asynctorage.getItem('url') : [{"url":"192.168.2.100:3000","alias":"test"},{"url":"111.222.3.444:5555","alias":"prod"}]

Comment: after the code is updated the same error still appears: TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '... this.state.url.map ...')

Comment: this shouldn't happen since the code already checking to make sure this.state.url is not undefined. do you have anywhere else that has this.state.url.map?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't figured out the data types and usages that AsyncStorage can store at all. I suggest you read the official documents in detail.

Of course, there is also an open source library that can help you access the data in AsyncStorage more conveniently. It will help with data storage, retrieval, and type conversion. You can access any data in AsyncStorage like memory objects.

[react-native-easy-app](https://github.com/chende008/react-native-easy-app/blob/master/README.en-US.md)